# iPhone developer certificate

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, certificate

I have a problem after upgrading my iPhone SDK 3.0. Xcode does not get the developer certificate, but it's in the key chain.

Comment: Remove certificate from Keychain. Download from member center and double click on it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the certificates are added to the `system` as opposed to the `login` keychains. When that happens XCode doesn't see the certificates. If this is the case, you have to go into "Keychain Access" (/Applications/Utilities) and add the certificate to the correct keychain (and optionally remove it from the wrong keychain).

Answer (score 0):

These certificates are the bane of a lot of iPhone developers lives. I've lost a lot of time wrestling with them.

All I can suggest - as there's too much to cover in detail - is that you read very carefully the help text that goes along with each section on the iPhone Developer Portal, paying more attention to the ones in red.

Answer (score 0):

I remeber having to delete and recreate them.  And if you've up graded to 3.0.1, [read this very carefully](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone%5Fsdk%5F3.1%5Fbeta%5F3/beta3%5Fabout%5Fiphone%5Fsdk%5Ffor%5Fiphone%5Fos%5F3.1.pdf)